# Minecraft: pull data from storage with a selector

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to get together a per player spawn setting mechanism and currently stuck on storing a position and player UUID together in a way where it's easily queryable and thus teleportable.

This is what i've tried so far:

```
/data modify entity 6f88f8eb-cfa3-44bf-a621-52b3e7d753e7 Pos set from storage game:player Spawn{target:'[{"selector":"@p"}]'}.location
```

That selector block is what isn't working. I need a way to get a selector working in that nbt search part.
if that's impossible something that drives the same functionality.
Also using a temp data storage would be acceptable if it's passable into that target based query :)

```
Storage game:player has the following contents: 
{
    Spawn:[
        {
            location: [-39.89557466099629d, 66.0d, 42.25176377238329d], 
            target: [I; -1155610777, -758824872, -1437747869, 728530035]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: no i was intendion modifying an armorstand's data and teleporting the player to that armor stand

Comment: Great! Just wanted to make sure that you knew, I figured that you would already know if you're this much involved with commands. May I ask what the data structure you're using looks like in the storage itself? It's much easier for us to visualize that, rather than only providing your test.

Comment: Spawn is a list that stores pairs of location and uuid . trying to match that UUID to the players UUID to get out a location i could use in moving an entity

Comment: Could you provide sample data by editing your question?

Comment: well i added the output of /data get there (and a bit of formatting for easy readability)

Comment: Can you use datapacks?

Comment: @randomuser922 yes actually trying to make a datapack myself. i was thinking if nothing else i could iterate through all items in Spawn and do a comparison on the user id stored in a temp storage. and then use that index to get the pos

Comment: That’s what I was thinking about doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this is, I copied the list of spawns to a new location. Then I iterated through them by copying the item in location 0 of the list to a temporary spot named `Current`, then removing it from the list so that the next iteration can get a new item.

```
# list_find.mcfunction --
# Set current to null to check if list is empty in the next step
data modify storage tools:iteration Current set value {}

# Set current to first item in list and check if it was successfull. if not loop wil exit if it hits iteration_continue.
execute store success storage tools:iteration IterationSuccess int 1 run data modify storage tools:iteration Current set from storage tools:iteration List[0]

# Remove currently processed item from list.
data remove storage tools:iteration List[0]

# Lists should always come as [Indexer, Item] pair lists 
data modify storage tools:compare A set from storage tools:iteration Current.Indexer
function tools:compare

# If list item is what we're searching for. run exit loop procedures.
execute if data storage tools:compare Success run function tools:iteration_exit

#if not continue iteration (until list is empty)
execute unless data storage tools:compare Success run function tools:iteration_continue
```

```
#iteration_exit.mcfunction --
data modify storage tools:iteration Result set from storage tools:iteration Current.Item
#tellraw @a [{"text":"iteration result: "},{"storage":"tools:iteration","nbt":"Result"}]

#iteration_continue.mcfunction --
#if list isn't empty run iterate again
execute if data storage tools:iteration IterationSuccess run function tools:list_find
#tellraw @a [{"text":"iter success: "},{"storage":"tools:iteration","nbt":"IterationSuccess"}]
```

Now, I just compare the Current.Indexer and the player UUID by writing over current with `/data modify`. However, because we need the current values later, we must store `Current.Indexer` in a temporary storage.

If they're different, `/data modify` returns 1. If they're the same, `/data modify` returns 0. Then, reverse the result with a scoreboard for later ease of use.

```
#compare.mcfunction --
#used by a vscode plugin for auto completion
#define storage tools:compare

# tellraw @a [{"text":"Compared: "},{"storage":"tools:compare","nbt":"A"},{"text":" and "},{"storage":"tools:compare","nbt":"B"}]
# If an overwrite happens, a 1 will be stored in Global(fake player)'s CTemp score. If values are the same, a 0 will be stored.
execute store success score CompFail Tools run data modify storage tools:compare A set from storage tools:compare B

# Reverse and set to storage tools:compare success
execute if score CompFail Tools matches 0 run data modify storage tools:compare Success set value 1
execute if score CompFail Tools matches 1 run data modify storage tools:compare Success set value 0
#tellraw @a [{"text":"A == B: "},{"storage":"tools:compare","nbt":"Success"}]
```

If the comparison returns true, we can exit the loop and use the `Current.Indexer` to teleport a tagged armor stand to the location. aka we data modify the armor stand Pos to Current.Item. and then tp player  -> tagged armor stand

```
#spawn.mcfunction --
#prepare to find from spawns and get spawning player's coordinate.
data modify storage tools:compare B set from storage player:spawning ID
data modify storage tools:iteration List set from storage player:spawns List

function tools:list_find

data modify entity @e[tag=TPTarget,limit=1,sort=nearest] Pos set from storage tools:iteration Result
```

Comment: I usually write in chat's, which just needs fast writing, so capitalization and such usually get forgotten, unless I specifically think about it. Which, this time, I only thought about it when I posted the question. Also my grammar skills ain't 100% anyways.

Comment: Absolutely no problem—you're not the only one who mistook this site for a traditional forum when you started, I almost did, too! And its okay if you aren't perfect—we just need to see that you're trying.